# Unable to access shared variable of parent from child

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create a simple "top" program by forking a child as a timer then usleep(i_interval) in the child and printing every waking interval. The main program is always running a biased RR scheduler that gives each process a distribution of CPU. The child that has the timer basically does this:

```
while (1)
{
    usleep(i_interval);
    print_top(process_queue);
}
```

the process queue is a struct that contains information I want to print, namely PID/COMMAND/TIME/%CPU. To share the variables which I'm changing in parent with the timer child I created a shared struct like so:

```
typedef struct process_context
{
    pid_t pid;
    char *command;
    int proportion;
    int proportion_cpu;
    int total_time;
    int order;
} process_context_t;

static process_context_t *process_queue;
process_queue = mmap(NULL, 
   sizeof(process_context_t *) * schedulees_count, 
   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
   MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

the child process then calls a function from the parent process

```
void print_top(process_context_t *process_queue)
```

that prints all the needed information. The issue however is when I get to this part, a section of print_top:

```
printf("test 1\n");
while (process_queue[l].pid != -1) {
    printf("test1.5\n");
    num_process++;
    l++;
}
printf("test 2\n");
```

the first printf works but everything else after that from the function no longer works. I'm assuming some kind of access error occurs at process_queue[l].pid?

Yet, when I tried a test program using a similar structure, it worked fine

```
typedef struct test_struct
{
    int test_val;
} test_struct_t;

test_struct_t *test_struct;

int main() {
    test_struct = mmap(NULL, sizeof(test_struct_t *) * 2, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                         MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    test_struct[0].test_val = 0;
    test_struct[1].test_val = 999;

    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("bad fork");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        while (1) {
            usleep(100000);
            printf("big %d\n", test_struct[1].test_val);
        }
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("bad fork");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        while (1) {
            usleep(300000);
            printf("small %d\n", test_struct[0].test_val);
        }
    }

    while(1) {
        usleep(1000000);

        test_struct[0].test_val++;
        test_struct[1].test_val--;

    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, how can I properly share the process_queue struct so the child can use it print every usleep()?

Comment: Haven't looked closely, but `sizeof(process_context_t *) * schedulees_count, ` feels wrong.  Why are you allocating space for pointer to process_context_t?  Pretty sure you want `sizeof(struct process_context) * schedules_count`.  Style suggestion: drop the typedefs and don't use `_t` suffix for your own names. I believe `_t` is reserved for the implemtation.

Comment: You seem to be defining *two* variables named `process_queue`?

Comment: On an unrelated note, even if the array of `process_context_t` structures are shared, the structure contains a pointer to possible un-shared memory.

Comment: the double declaration was a mistake in the post, corrected it to reflect. Also, @WilliamPursell you're right, process_queue is an array of process_context_t and I have changed the allocation to accordingly. However, code still fails to work.. What is the possible unshared memory? process_queue[l].pid? Should I mmap every single item in the struct? Seems like the struct variables were shared in the test case, although I didn't use an array of test_structs so could that affect anything?

Comment: The `command` member. If it's a pointer to a null-terminated string (which I guess) then that string have to be allocated in shared memory as well. You might want to consider making it an array.

Comment: regarding statements like: `perror("bad fork");`   When that error message is sent to `stderr`, via the call to `perror()` the program should never continue executing, so the next statements should be: cleanup then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the posted code fails to release the memory obtained via the call to: `mmap()` before exiting

Comment: OT: always check the returned value from `mmap()` to assure the operation was successful